# How to create tunnel from your local windows machine to remote windows server

Tags: ssh, proxy, sshd, socks-proxy

I have a jump host at my work environment, what have access to some specific servers like  san drive and few web based dashboards are only accessible from this server.
Every time i have connect to this server using windows RDC and do my tasks. I want to know if there is any possibility that i can tunnel my local traffic using this windows server.
Lets say I have reports dashboard at **http://10.10.10.1:8080** which is only accessible from **10.10.10.10**,
Is there any way 1 can access this from my local machine by simple adding proxy address in my browser. I am doing same for few other linux servers using `ssh -D 9095 user@host` and then adding proxy address and port in my web browser. But don`t know how to achieve this in case of windows server(windows server 2012 R2).

Comment: I do this with an IPsec VPN connection from my machine to the remote network (using the whole subnet) and so access to all devices remote.

Comment: I am already connected using my work vpn but this restriction in still there. And few machines are only connected via these jump hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The special handling of `\\TSCLIENT\<sharename>`, as well as `RDPCLIP` which forwards newly captured clipboard content in both directions, are closest to the tunneling you are describing. The RDP protocol does seem provide the bits and pieces that would let you write a tunneller, but long ago I threw a few days at the problem and got nowhere.

***late update:*** Apparently the app [rdp2tcp](http://rdp2tcp.sourceforge.net/) does what you wish.

> rdp2tcp is a tunneling tool on top of remote desktop protocol (RDP). It uses RDP virtual channel capabilities to multiplex several ports forwarding over an already established rdesktop session.

---

As an alternative, perhaps you could look into using the [RemoteApp](https://serverfault.com/a/354165/190386) feature. Using this, the browser would run on the remote server (10.10.10.10) but be presented to you on your own laptop as a normal window. [More information](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/introducing-remoteapp-and-desktop-connections/ba-p/246803). This would be simpler and likely more acceptable by your company's security standards than rdp2tcp.